# How to create a bootable USB from one ISO file securely from the shell?

Tags: linux, boot, usb, iso-image

I know `dd` utility is often cited, but I would consider it unsafe as it could harm the system when mis-selecting a system drive.

So I'd like to create a bootable USB drive from a hybrid ISO file in one shell command-line, is there any utility to achieve that?

Answer (score 7):

[`bootiso` BASH script](https://github.com/jsamr/bootiso) was carefully designed as a user-friendly command line utility to securely create bootable USB sticks from ISO files in one line.

#### Typical usage

```
bootiso file.iso
```

#### Features

- prevent you from damaging the system by asserting selected device is connected through USB
- smartly inspects ISO file to handle both hybrid and non-hybrid ISOs, installing SYSLINUX bootlaoder when needed, boosting the odds USB will be bootable
- autoselect a USB drive if there is exactly one connected to your system
- prompt user for confirmation before erasing anything
- check ISO file mime type
- carefully linted and validated with [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)

#### See it in action

In this example, options `--assume-yes` and `--autoselect` (shorten `-ay`) allow user to create a bootable USB from ISO in one line by autoselecting the one and only USB drive connected to its system and bypassing the confirmation step. If more than one USB drive is detected, user will still be prompted to select one.

[image]

#### Quick install

```
curl -L https://git.io/bootiso -O
chmod +x bootiso
```

Comment: Great tool and great support via Github, thank you!